# Use pointer array to store all intermediate results of factorial calculation

Tags: c++, pointers, factorial

I want to use a pointer to array to store all the intermediate results of factorial calculation. The code below get crush when running. Why and how can I modify the code so that it can run correctly?

```
int factorial(int x, int *p){
    if (x>1){
        *p = x*factorial(x-1, p+1); 
        return *p;
    }
    else{
        *p = 1;
        return 1;   
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with *pointer array*?

Comment: How are you calling the code?

Comment: You may use `std::vector`.

Comment: What did you pass into factorial()as p?

Comment: @Deduplicator I mean array pointer

Comment: @timrau The call will be like 
int *p = new int(10);
int x = factorial(4, p);

Comment: Oh, that’s very bad. That’s not an array at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it with

```
int *p = new int[10];
```

Your original code

```
int *p = new int(10);
```

means allocating space for one single int and initialize it as 10, not a 10-element array.

Comment: Does it illegal to write code like
int *p = new int(10) ? 
Or it means something else?

Comment: Thanks. I personally think this is a bad questions since it actually do nothing with recursion and array. Sorry for the distraction.